# Method not allowed - 405 Error - with Twilio API, using flask and python, heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, twilio, http-status-code-405

I was following a Twilio tutorial on sending SMS through the API. I followed all the steps, however, I am receiving a 405 error. My code:

```
from flask import Flask
from twilio import twiml
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/sms', methods=['POST'])
def sms():
    r = twiml.Response()
    r.sms("This is awesome!")
    return str(r)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))

    if port == 5000:
        app.debug = True

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

I am getting a 405 error (method not allowed), when calling my url, which looks like: http://my-url.herokuapp.com/sms, which is also associated like this to the twilio account. When I include 'GET', everything works, this is not according to tutorial however. Any hints?

Comment: That URL will only work if you `POST` something to it, if you just access it in the browser as you have done, you'll get `405` because the URL is only mapped for POST. What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the repository](https://github.com/RobSpectre/Reasons-Sonya-Is-Awesome) it seems that you will actually need to text to the number that Twillo is proxying for you.  If you want to access the URL in your browser as well you will need to add `'GET'` to the `methods` list (as you discovered).